# Is it possible to proot into an Android rootfs?

Tags: file-system

Where can i download an android rootfs? I was wondering will it be possible to use Android on Linux using (proot)

Comment: Your question is a bit short so that most people will not understand it. I would recommend to edit and extend it especially explain in detail what you are trying to do and how. I assume you use Termux?

Comment: Android is distributed as ROMs, not as a simple rootfs. `chroot` / `proot` is possible only for UNIX / Linux environments which can be entirely run from CLI. But Android is by-design a GUI operating system which requires a lot of hardware-specific proprietary code to load before the GUI loads. So you cannot run Android in `chroot`. Android's shell environment is very very limited, meant to be run for debugging, not as a complete operating system.

Comment: @IrfanLatif nevermind. A shell environment is good enough :)